# Vertices of polyhedron given the number of faces and the shape of each face.

Tags: geometry

I was practicing for a high school math competition when I was asked this question:

**Each face of a rhombic dodecahedron is a rhombus. How many vertices are there?**

We are expected to know that a dodecahedron has 12 faces, and that F-E+V=2, but the question does not give the number of edges, but instead the shape of each face.

Comment: Get the number of edges this way: count the number of edges on all the faces. Because each edge bounds two faces, that number double-counts the edges; so, divide by $2$.

Answer (score 1):

I just visualize the figure in my head and count:

[image]

[image]

But a more principled method is to use Euler's equation.

If each face were separate, there would be $12 \cdot 4 = 48$ edges.  However when each rhombus is attached to another, each edge gets "used" by two rhombuses, so the total number of edges becomes $24$.

So Euler's equation gives:

$$F - E + V = 2$$

or

$$12 - 24 + V = 2$$

so $$V = 14.$$